# How to make bigger Macintosh HD partition

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, disk-utility, esxi

I installed OS X Mavericks Server as a virtual machine to ESX.
I'm doing some testing and now I need more space. 
Macintosh HD partition is 50 GB and I have expand it to 100 GB total in ESX but I need also to expand Macintosh HD partition in OS X.

Until now I have tried this:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17901/how-can-i-resize-a-partition-with-disk-utility

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/why-cant-i-resize-my-existing-partition?rq=1

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14689/disk-utility-shrink-1-partition-expand-the-other?rq=1

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21789/how-can-i-resize-my-lion-partition-to-fill-up-the-unused-space-on-the-drive?rq=1

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29892/disk-utility-cant-add-partitions?rq=1

When I run `diskutil list` in Terminal, this is what i get:

[image: Output]

As you can see at GUID_partition_scheme, total space is 107.4 GB.

**What I want is:**

- delete disk1s3
- expand disk1s2 (Macintosh HD) to 100 GB